# How can I show only some words in a line using sed?

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I'm trying to use sed to show only the `1st`, `2nd`, and `8th` word in a line.

The problem I have is that the words are random, and the amount of spaces between the words are also random...  For example:

```
QST334   FFR67     HHYT  87UYU HYHL 9876S   NJI QD112    989OPI
```

Is there a way to get this to output as just the 1st, 2nd, and 8th words:

```
QST334 FFR67 QD112
```

Thanks for any advice or hints for the right direction!

Comment: Use `cut` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$8}' file
```

---

In action:

```
$ echo "QST334 FFR67 HHYT 87UYU HYHL 9876S NJI QD112 989OPI" | awk '{print $1,$2,$8}'
QST334 FFR67 QD112
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to put `" "` between two columns as mentioned in another answer. By default `awk` consider single white space as output field separator AKA `OFS`. so you just need commas between the desired columns.

so following is enough:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$8}' file
```

For Example:

```
echo "QST334   FFR67     HHYT  87UYU HYHL 9876S   NJI QD112    989OPI" |awk '{print $1,$2,$8}'
QST334 FFR67 QD112
```

However, if you wish to have some other `OFS` then you can do as follow:

```
echo "QST334   FFR67     HHYT  87UYU HYHL 9876S   NJI QD112    989OPI" |awk -v OFS="," '{print $1,$2,$8}'
QST334,FFR67,QD112
```

Note that this will put a comma between the output columns.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the [`cut` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
cut --delimiter '<delimiter-character>' --fields <field> <file>
```

Where:

- *`'<delimiter-character>'>`*: is the delimiter on which the string should be parsed.
- *`<field>`*: specifies which column to output, could a single column `1`, multiple columns `1,3` or a range of them `1-3`.

In action:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1-3 /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g;s/.*/echo "&"|sed -n "1p;2p;8p"/e;y/\n/ /' file
```

Convert spaces to newlines. Evaluate each line as a separate file and print only the required lines i.e. fields. Replace remaining newlines with spaces.